# Routing from SPAs inside MVC areas

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am moving my mvc application in angularjs. 
I have different areas in the application. I want to move between areas using MVC routing. And I want to use Angular routing inside each area.

So in my server I have default routing configuration... and in my angular I have the following configuration:

```
.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {                
    var viewBase = '/Views/AngularTemplates/';

    $routeProvider
        .when('/Servizi/Cpe/New', {
            templateUrl: viewBase + 'Cpes/insert.html',
            controller: 'cpesController'
        })
        .when('/Servizi/Cpe', {
            templateUrl: viewBase + 'Cpes/list.html',
            controller: 'cpesController'
        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})
```

`Servizi` is my area and `Cpe` is the controller in the area... When I move from `/Servizi/Cpe` to `/Servizi/Cpe/New` it works because it is managed by angular.

But I cannot move from `/Home` to `/Servizi` because it's managed by MVC routing.

How can do that ?

Answer (score 0):

A very quick solution to move between 'areas' would be:

```
window.location.href = "myAreaPath/mypage.asp";
```

Try it and tell us if work for you ;)

Comment: but where should I add that line?

Comment: For example, as a link: <a onclick=" window.location.href='Servizi/' ">Servizi</a>